# How to obtain the ActualWidth of a WPF Popup

Tags: wpf, popup, actualwidth, wpf-positioning

I am trying to place a `Popup` element in a specific position, relative to the `Placement` control.

In order to achieve that I need to find out the `ActualWidth` of the popup control.
But trying to get this value before or after displaying the popup (IsOpen = True) it always returns 0.

Unfortunately I cannot hard code the size of the popup.

How can I determine the `ActualWidth`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried getting the `ActualWidth` of the popup's child element?

Comment: Down-voted because the actual width of the child element is 0.